# Ideal products and calculating with ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring and $I,J$ ideals of $R$. Let $$IJ = \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i \big\vert\ n \geq 0, a_1,\cdots, a_n \in I, b_1,\cdots,b_n \in J \right\}$$
> i) Show that IJ is an ideal of R and $IJ \subset I \cap J$.
>
> ii) Let $K$ be another ideal of $R$. Show that $I(J + K) = IJ + IK$.

i)

In order to show that $IJ$ is an ideal, I need to show that $\forall r \in R\ \forall s \in IJ: r s r^{-1} \in IJ$, right?

Let $r \in R$ be arbitrary, $s\in IJ = (a_1b_1)+\cdots+(a_kb_k)$. $rsr^{-1} = r( (a_1b_1)+\cdots+(a_kb_k))r^{-1} = (\underbrace{ra_1}_{\in I}b_1)+\cdots+(\underbrace{ra_k}_{\in I}b_k) \in IJ$, as I is an ideal of R, and therefore any $r\cdot a_i$ is, right?

So what about $IJ \subset I \cap J$? If I consider a single summand $a_ib_k$, that the result need to be in I as well as in J, because both are ideals of R. But why does this apply for the whole sum?

ii)

I have no idea, do you have a hint for me?

Comment: R is commutative?

Comment: wrong definition. you need to show $rs$ is in the ideal whenever $r$ is in the ring and $s$ is in the ideal and that's for a left ideal.

Comment: You seem to be confusing normal subgroups (which involves conjugation) with ideals. Make sure you know what the meaning of the words you're using are. Note that it's not necessarily the case that all $r\in R$ even *have* an inverse $r^{-1}$. In particular, zero divisors can't have inverses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1). Let $s = \sum a_ib_i \in IJ, r \in R.$ We need to show that $rs, sr \in IJ.$ Now $rs = \sum (ra_i)b_i \in IJ$ (since $I$ is an ideal) and $sr = \sum a_i(b_ir) \in IJ$ (since $J$ is an ideal).

To show that $IJ \subseteq I \cap J,$ first note that for any $a \in I, b\in J$ we have $ab \in I$ and $ab \in J$ (using the fact that both $I, J$ are ideals) and hence $ab \in I \cap J.$ Since $I \cap J$ is an ideal, $\sum a_ib_i \in I \cap J, \forall a_i \in I, b_i \in J$ ("sum" is a finite sum).

(2). $s = \sum a_i(b_i+c_i) \in I(J+K) \Rightarrow s = \sum (a_ib_i + a_ic_i) = \sum a_ib_i + \sum a_ic_i \in IJ + IK.$ For the reverse inclusion, first note that $J \subseteq J+K, K \subseteq J +K.$ So we have $IJ \subseteq I(J+K), IK \subseteq I(J+K)$ and hence $IJ + IK \subseteq I(J+K).$